# Create new dictionaries based upon the keys of an original directory

Tags: python, dictionary, key

So I have a dictionary filled with network traffic from a csv file. Each key is a source address. For example:

```
52.113.56.149
[['tcp','https','34.567.12.899','2'...]['udp','https',...]]
```

Each flow of a particular source address contains various values and are contained like this [[flow1],[flow2]...]. But each source address does not contain the same number of flows. How do I create a new dictionary for each source address (the keys in original dictionary?)

Edit:
The original dictionary is called datadict and is formatted like above, so each key (the source address) has values (when I print out the dict it looks like this :

```
12.464.67.478
[['tcp','https','etc],[another flow]...]

35.482.19.191
[['udp','...']]
```

But from the original dictionary I want new dictionaries based upon the source address. So each new dictionary is the source address and the flows that came from that source address.

Comment: What do you want the key-value pairs to be in the new dictionary?

Comment: Can you post the 'original dictionary'?

Comment: I want each source address from the original dictionary to map to its flows associated with it, each flow contains the src port, dest port, number of bytes, etc. But I want each flow to be separated. If that makes sense @yinnonsanders

Comment: Could you post a slightly larger example and your desired output from that example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
val = [['tcp','https','34.567.12.899','2'...]['udp','https',...]]

new_dict = {i[2]:i[:2]+i[3:] for i in val}
```

This will output the IP address as a key and the additional information as the values stored in a list:

```
{'34.567.12.899': ['tcp', 'https', '2'....], ....}
```

This example uses dict comprehension to take the second element of the list, which is the IP address, and then stores the rest of the data in the list as the value, without the IP address. The splicing for the values takes up to the third element, not counting the second element, and then adds that sublist to the remainder of the list from the third element onward.

Edit:

Here is a way to store your data so that the source address is also contained in the values:

```
new_dict = {i[2]:i for i in val}
```

Comment: Yes I want the new dictionaries to be based upon the source address. Could you explain a little more in detail about how this works? new_dict = {i[2]:i[:2]+i[3:] for i in val}'

Comment: Please see my recent edit. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, that helps! What would I do if I wanted to include the source address in the values? Or do you think that would be redundant? (I'm trying to build a dataframe and pass this info through a model eventually) @Ajax1234

Comment: @melb27 I do not see a direct need for to include the source address in the values as you can always access the address by key. However, I will post a solution that keeps the source address as a key, but also retain it in the values.